# Jackcess get a sorted table or biggest index in it

Tags: java, ms-access, insert, indexing, jackcess

I want to insert a row in a jackcess table that gets created like this;

`Table t = Database.open(new File(dbUrl)).getTable(tname);`

Normally, if I was using SQL, this would be the right time to sort it. Even so, I have looked at the documentation and found nothing on it.

Anyway, after getting the table, I try inserting a row in it by using;

```
        int id = t.getRowCount() + 1;

        try {
            t.addRow(id, "MyName", "MyLastName");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But, since the index is not sorted, I get the following exception;

```
java.io.IOException: New row [250, MyName, MyLastName, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null] violates uniqueness constraint for index 
Data number: 5
Page number: 99
Is Backing Primary Key: true
Is Unique: true
Ignore Nulls: false
Columns: [ColumnDescriptor  Name: (CLIENTES) ID_CLIENTE
Type: 0x4 (LONG)
Number: 0
Length: 4
Variable length: false flags: 1]
Initialized: true
EntryCount: 249
    Cache: 
    LeafDataPage[99] 0, 0, (0), [RowId = 93:0, Bytes = 7F 80 00 00  00 , RowId = 6844:0, Bytes = 7F 80 00 01  5C]

at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.IndexData.addEntry(IndexData.java:571)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.IndexData.addRow(IndexData.java:537)
...
```

Now, I thought that maybe it was failing because of the lack of other columns but then I tried using 
    `t.getRowCount() + 100;` 
 and was able to insert. So my problem clearly is that I have no idea how to get the index or the sorted table.

Obviously, counting the rows is a lousy solution. I just tried it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the rows in sorted order you can iterate through a Cursor that has been backed by an Index. The following code, using the technique described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19304549/2144390), runs through the table in Primary Key order and retrieves the largest key value. It then adds a new row with the next largest key value.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;

public class jackcessTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Table table = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb")).getTable("JackcessTest");
            int LargestKey = 0;
            // the following loop is modified from 
            //     https://stackoverflow.com/a/19304549/2144390
            //     for Jackcess 2.0
            for(Row row : CursorBuilder.createCursor(table.getPrimaryKeyIndex())) {
                LargestKey = (int)row.get("ID");
            }
            try {
                table.addRow(LargestKey + 1, "MyName", "MyLastName");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");        
    }
}
```