# Sort a table in Jackcess

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

I work with an MS-Access table in Java using Jackcess:

```
Database mdb = Database.open(new File(myPath));
Table myTable = mdb.getTable("TableName");
```

Is there a way to get the table sorted/ordered by one or more column(s)? Couldn't find anything in the docs.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you iterate through the Table rows using a Cursor which is backed by an Index, you will get the rows ordered by the relevant Index.

This is an example (using the 1.x API) which iterates the table based on the order of the primary key:

```
for(Map<String,Object> row : Cursor.createIndexCursor(table, table.getPrimaryKeyIndex())) {
  // do something with row here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I modified your example to sort by other columns (not primary key) and it works if I manually specify an index before! Unfortunatelly I have data in hundreds of files and do not want to edit all of them manually.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue here, but it helped.

For the folks that are using the new version of Jackcess (v: 2.1.2) here is the answer:

```
for (Row row : CursorBuilder.createCursor(table.getIndex("IndexToBeSorted"))){

           //Your awesome code with the row here      

}
```

Thanks!